# Android - Qual a diferença entre getReadableDatabase() e getWritableDatabase()?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Eu consegui inserir informações no banco de dados fazendo o uso do método `getReadableDatabase()`. Nesse caso não deveria dar erro? Não deveria ser o método `getWritableDatabase()`?

```
private void savePet() {

        petDbHelper = new PetDbHelper(this);
        db = petDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME, mNameEditText.getText().toString());
        values.put(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_BREED, mBreedEditText.getText().toString());
        values.put(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_WEIGHT, mWeightEditText.getText().toString());
        values.put(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_GENDER, mGender);

        long newRowID =
                db.insert(PetEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

        /** Display rowID after finish */
        Toast.makeText(this, "New row added: " + newRowID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        /** Close Activity */
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: [Documentação - getReadableDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getReadableDatabase())

Comment: Ambos retornam o mesmo objeto

Comment: @wmsouza em muitos casos, o é fácil não entender exatamente o que fala a documentação.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html?hl=pt-br#getReadableDatabase()), o `getReadableDatabase()`:

> Create and/or open a database. This will be the same object returned
>   by getWritableDatabase() unless some problem, such as a full disk,
>   requires the database to be opened read-only

Traduzindo:

> Cria ou abre um banco de dados. Este será o mesmo objecto retornado
>   por `getWritableDatabase()`, a não ser que ocorra um problema, como
>   por exemplo: se o disco estiver cheio o banco de dados é aberto no
>   modo só de leitura.

Mas olhando para a documentação do [getWritableDatabase()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase()), ela diz que se o disco estiver cheio, este método retornará um erro.

**Resumindo**: Ambos retornam o mesmo objecto, por isso não há erro. Mas você deve usar o `getWritableDatabase()` para guardar dados para poder lidar melhor com os erros que podem surgir.